# HttpURLConnection returning only few bytes

Tags: java

I have:

```
InputStream input = null;
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
URL url = new URL("...");

connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
String zam = "...";
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",zam);
connection.connect();

int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
input = connection.getInputStream();
byte data[] = new byte[400];
int count;
count = input.read(data);
connection.disconnect();
String str1 = new String(data);
```

str1, the response is always only:

!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-/

nothing more.
But when I turn off the cookie:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Cookie",zam);
```

everything is OK;

Thanks ind adv for reply.
Adi.

Comment: everything is OK, as in you get the complete file? How long is the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is that you don't read all the data from the stream. Try to use a method like this.

```
public static String streamToString(final InputStream is, final int bufferSize) throws Exception {
    final char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    final StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    try (Reader in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")) {
        int rsz = 0;
        while ((rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) > 0) {
            out.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
        }
    }
    return out.toString();
}
```

And also read this answer about other methods [How do I read / convert an InputStream into a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-do-i-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, but what is rsz?

Comment: Can bufferSize be any size?

Comment: Sorry. Just fixed about `rsz`. That's a count of bytes that were actually read from the stream. The buffer could be any size. Usually from 1024 bytes.